# How to import python dbconfig file in laravel 5.6

Tags: python, database, laravel, pandas, insert

In my Laravel project, I have added python pandas code for data separation and insertion into a database. if I declare database username password and database name in python then I am able to insert the CSV file created directly into database but when now I cannot declare username and password in python always because the username and password will be changing so I want to add the username and password to a config file and import it into python. so I can write the config file with Laravel code whenever I want. I tried some ways but it didn't work.

**My code so far is.**

```
config.py
import pymysql

db = pymysql.connect( 
   host = "localhost" ,
   user = "root" ,
   passwd = "root")


file.py
import config as db
cursor = db.cursor()
csv_data = csv.reader(open('v.csv'))
next(csv_data)
for row in csv_data:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO dbname.tablename(fields1, field2, ...) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)',row)
db.commit()
cursor.close()
```

If I put the entire code in a file.py, I am able to insert the data but I want to import it into file.py.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I get you well, you can try [Symfony's process component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) and execute python from there. That way you can pass laravel's input arguments dynamically.